# bash script to retrieve the highest numbered folder/directory

Tags: bash

I am currently running a program that rearranges genomes to create the best alignment to a reference genome, and as it does so it generates a number of folders like *alignment#*.

I have no way of knowing how many iterations this program will run through before it stops, but the final alignment is the best one (could be anything from `alignment5` to `alignment35`) and will have a predictable filename within the folder, though the folder will be changeable.

I need a bash script that will look inside a directory and identify the highest-numbered directory and store it as a variable or similar, that could ideally be passed to an additional program.

I just wanted to add that my scripting is very basic. If you guys could explain your answers as thoroughly as possible or provide links to user-friendly resources that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concept script here:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob || exit
DIR="/parent/dir" highest=

for a in "$DIR"/alignment+([[:digit:]]); do
    b=${a##*/alignment}
    [[ -z $highest || b -gt highest ]] && highest=$b
done

[[ -n $highest ]] && echo "Highest: $DIR/alignment${highest}"
```

Comment: Much appreciated, works like a charm. Could you explain a little about what each line is doing though as I've never come across shopt and I'm still unclear on a lot of the syntax in for loops.

Comment: `shopt` enables `extglob` for extended pattern matching. `'+([[:digit:]])` is a form of extended pattern matching which matches 1 more or more digits. You can't do it with normal globbing. `B=${A#/alignment}` removes everything besides the number in the pathname.

Comment: This one's a pretty good discussion about extended globbing: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing

Comment: As for this condition check: `-z $HIGHEST` tests if HIGHEST already has value set in it. If it's empty it would mean a true condition and HIGHEST would be set to `$B`. Otherwise (with `||`) if `B` is greater than previous value set on `HIGHEST` (`B -gt HIGHEST`), `HIGHEST` gets refreshed with a new value from `$B` as well.

Comment: Very neat script thanks very much! That extglob link was extremely useful too, cheers! :D

Comment: there seems to something wrong with it, HIGHEST always remains empty

Comment: @DanDan Maybe the directory isn't found. Try to debug with `-x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 $directory | sort --numeric
```

This assumes a consistent prefix to the file names.
Otherwise, you can use "sort -k N --numeric", see "man sort" for details.